# docker-compose right path to show symfony starting page

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose

I'm deploying a project with docker and I want to have the Symfony basic starting page to show up but I cannot seem to understand what is the correct path.

[This is my project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1UsT.png)

And this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

x-cache-from:
  - &app-cache-from
    cache_from:
      - php:8.0-fpm

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: usr
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pwd
      POSTGRES_DB: db
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw

    ports:
      - target: 5432
        published: 5432
        protocol: tcp
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "81:80"

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
    volumes:
      - /api
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./docker/logs:/var/log
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"

  php-fpm:
    image: php:8.0-fpm
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    build:
      context: ./docker/php-fpm
      <<: *app-cache-from
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
      - APP_SECRET=${APP_SECRET}
    volumes:
      - /api
```

I always have the same error :
`docker-php-fpm-1  | Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www`

I don't grasp everything with the nginx conf and stuff

Comment: There is no reference to any symfony project ! Is it normal ? Please have a look at this : https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker

Comment: It's the /api folder where is stored all the symfony projects

Comment: And did you installer symfony inside that folder ?

Comment: Yes ! I have a symfony skeleton project inside

Comment: Is the docker file located at the root of the symfony project? In the same place, you have to put the .docker folder. In the screenshot, there is no dot in front of the folder but in your docker-compose yes and there is no symfony files, just an .env...

Comment: in ``volumes`` try to replace ``/api`` with ``.:/api``

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! I got it working by changing the path in volumes  - ./api:/var/www/ in nginx and php-fpm